# Why an union is faster than a group by

Tags: sql

Well, maybe I am too old school and I would like to understand the following.

query 1.

```
select count(*), gender from customer
group by gender
```

query 2.

```
select count(*), 'M' from customer
where gender ='M'
union
select count(*), 'F' from customer
where gender ='F'
```

the 1st query is simpler, but for some reason in the profiler,when I execute both at the same time, it says that query 2 uses 39% of the time, and query 1, 61%.

I would like to understand the reason, maybe I have to rewrite all my queries.

Comment: Just a guess: the second query has actually no aggregation, and no state is kept in order to calculate the counts (it is just returning number of matched rows for `count(*)`)

Comment: what do you mean `at the same time`?

Comment: I presume you only have 2 genders and everyone has a gender assigned rather than some being `NULL`? Also what if you try `UNION ALL`? Does that improve the second one even more? Also what RDBMS and what do the execution plans look like? Also relative costs in SQL Server execution plans don't necessarily reflect real performance if that's what you are using to compare the two queries.

Comment: What database are you using? What is the execution plan?

Comment: Can you show the full results from the profiler?  CPU Time, Reads, Execution Time, etc, etc?  *(Not from the `execution plan`, but from the actual `profiler` application.)*

Comment: And what if you try `select count(*), gender from customer where gender in ('F','M') group by gender`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query 2 is actually a nice trick. It works like this: You have an index on gender. The DBMS can seek into that index two times to get two ranges of rows (one for M and one for F). It doesn't need to read anything from these rows, just that they exist. It can count the number of rows that exist in the two ranges.

In the first query the DBMS needs to decode the rows to read the gender, then it needs to either sort the rows or build a hashtable to aggregate them. That is more expensive than just counting rows.

Comment: An index on gender could be used for a stream aggregate on the first query too. No sorting required as they are already in index order.

Comment: True, yet the rows need to be decoded and compared to each other.

Comment: The rows need to be decoded in an index seek too so it knows when it has reached the last row matching the seek predicate and should stop scanning.

Comment: I don't think this is of any use to put an index on genders except in this very specific case

Comment: Hm ok we really need to look at the plans I guess.

Comment: There is an advantage to indexes on non-sparse fields when you have queries that access only one column and the rows are quite wide.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure?
Maybe the second query is just using cached resources from the first on.

run them in two separately batches and before each one run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to clean the cache. Then compare the values of each execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The optimization of a query depends on the database.  What you are seeing is database specific.

The union, as written, would naively require two passes through the data, doing a filter and a count.  Basically no other storage is necessary.

The aggregation might sort the data and then do a count.  Or, it might generate a hash table.  Given the performance difference, I would guess a sort is being used.  Clearly, this is overkill for this type of query.

If you have an index on gender, both methods would essentially scan the index so the performance should be similar (the union version might scan it twice=.

Does the database that you are using offer a way to calculate statistics on tables?  If so, you should update the statistics and see if you still get the same results.

Also, can you post the results of "explain" or the execution plan?  That would precisely explain why one is faster than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an equivalent query, but found the opposite result; the union took 65% and the 'group by' took 35%.  (Using SQL Server 2008).  I do not have an index on gender so my execution plan shows a clustered index scan.  Unless you examine the execution plan in detail, it really isn't possible to explain this result.

Adding an index for this query is probably not a good idea, since you are probably not going to be running this query nearly as often as you are going to insert records in the customer table.  In some other database engines with bitmap indexes (Oracle, PostgreSQL), the database engine can combine multiple indexes, so that can alter the utility of single column indexes. But in SQL Server, you need to design the indexes to 'cover' the commonly used queries.